# How do I build and configure a local CPAN module repo?

Tags: perl, bugzilla, cpan

I'm a sys admin administering three air gapped (zero internet access) supercomputers.  On one of the supercomputers we need to run Bugzilla.  I already built my own local yum repository, but now I need to get Bugzilla up and running, which requires a local CPAN.  I built a local CPAN on my laptop following the instructions I found here:

http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col42.html

And rsync'd the CPAN over to the supercomputer's home directory.  When I went back into the Bugzill dir to run the installation, the install-module.pl can't find a local CPAN directory.  How do I configure my supercomputer's perl to automatically know where its local CPAN lives so I can finish my Bugzilla task?

Comment: Does the CPAN.pm shell work at all? Can you do `cpan` and then run `test Some::CPAN::Module`?

Comment: Yes.  But it tells me it can't find the needed packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  And I hope this helps anyone traveling the same dark path that I've been on.  Apparently, when the config process seemingly asks
for 5 different paths for sources, authors, etc for the new local
CPAN...what it really means it to give it ONE path.  Just one.  Five
times.

Like so:  /root/CPAN/

NOT:

/root/CPAN/
then
/root/CPAN/sources/
then
/root/CPAN/authors/

Nope, just the same root path to CPAN for all the paths the config process asks you for (this is for a fully rsync'd CPAN build).

Yay Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Does setting up Bugzilla actually require a local CPAN?

Depending on what OS your supercomputers run, perhaps there are packages for a number of the Perl modules. And, for those for which there are not, or for where the package is too old, you can either:

- create newer packages; or
- manually install the modules in the $BUGZILLA_HOME/lib directory; or
- CPAN-install them on another box running the same OS, and then just copy across the entire "lib" directory

Gerv
(Bugzilla developer)

Comment: I guess I was leaning towards the CPAN because there seemed to be quite a few modules.  Now that I have the CPAN built, how can I set the configuration on the server to point things to it that need Perl packages?  Or am I oversimplifying it?

Comment: So I've all but given up on configuring CPAN to be used locally.  I did build one from an rsync...but nothing works.  I set /root/CPAN/as the url for it in urllist, but I keep getting the msg "Warning: no success downloading '/root/CPAN/source/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp160800'."

Anyway, do I just untar the module in the lib dir you mention here?  For all of those modules?  Why does Perl stuff have to be so cryptic?